# Mexican Travel to Germany

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-accommodation, mexican-citizens

I have some questions as Mexicans dont need visa for Germany.

I plan to make a trip of only two weeks to Germany.

Will, they are questioned at the airport/Immigration?

such as Where is He/She staying/Hotel Booking?

How much money you have?

How much money should I have in my account/Cash to declare immigration?

And if I have a letter of invitation from a person in Germany, how much money should I show to immigration?

Or at the airport, nobody will ask anything about these things?

Thanks

Comment: I should think you can expect all, one of, or any combination of these type of questions, together with proof of means to return - according to Timatic, visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry. https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b The subsistence requirement for Germany varies depending on the traveller’s circumstances https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_25.pdf

Comment: @Traveller, if you have this much information please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

They may or may not ask.

You should **have a plan** where you stay after you leave the airport, e.g. a hotel reservation or the invitation of a friend. They might ask you about this plan to gauge your *credibility*. They want to see if you react like a tourist who has just spent a day in an aircraft, or like an illegal immigrant who can't even remember the birthdate in his own passport.

Do not "show" money unless they ask about money. You should have enough money (cash or bank account) for your stay and the return trip. Without an invitation that covers room and board, that should be roughly €45/day.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think it’s likely you’ll be asked many questions, if any at all. However, if they *were* to ask you something, I think it’d be for proof of an airplane ticket of you leaving Schengen after 90 days of entering, or a credit card showing you have sufficient funds for your stay.

It’s advisable to always carry these things regardless of where you go.

Answer (score 1):

Like everywhere, immigration controls have the goal to make sure they let in people with legitimate reasons (tourism, business, visiting friends or family...) while keeping out people who are actually trying to immigrate (initially pretending they're just there for tourism, but planning to remain in the country, stay under the radar, work illegally, etc.).

This actually applies whether you need/have a visa or not. When you have a visa, most of those checks are done in advance (though at the border they may check for consistency). When you don't, this has to be checked when you enter then country (or the Schengen Area, in this case).

In the vast majority of cases, they **will** ask a few questions. They may be as innocent as "how long are you staying for", "what's the purpose of your visit" or "where are you staying", and then off you go. They may be a lot more detailed if the passport control officer has any doubt regarding the intentions of the traveler.

The traveler should have a return ticket they can show on demand.

They should have money or means of payment that allow them to sustain themselves, consistent with where they intend to stay. If they are staying with friends or family, less is expected than if you are staying in hotels. It doesn't need to be cash, credit or debit cards may be appropriate. But if they do have doubts, they can indeed ask for more details, like showing a balance or a credit limit that is consistent. If you are saying you are staying with someone, they may want to call them if they have any doubts.

The real keywords here are **consistency** and **credibility**. If your story is consistent and credible, it should be real easy and quick.

Comment: If I say i will stay with a friend do I need some kind of document for that, or just friend number and address is fine?