# Do I need a visa to travel to Trinidad as an Indian national?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, tourist-visas, trinidad-and-tobago

An Indian national traveling to Trinidad and back, what questions/documents are asked on arrival when you travel for short stay?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/154070/mexican-travel-to-germany?noredirect=1#comment383521_154070

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b), the database used by airlines, you will need two things, a passport and your return ticket.

You are required to bring a valid passport, that will remain valid during your entire stay, and said passport will need to be machine readable.

To enter you will also need to hold a return/onwards ticket that will depart before your visa free period of 90 days expires.